# How to run SQL TRANSACTION in a PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a SQL Transaction query that I am unable to run. Can any one tell me please why? I have failed to run it using `preparedstament.executequery();` as well.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT total_installment_remaining  FROM payment_loan WHERE loan_id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE payment_loan SET total_installment_remaining =total_installment_remaining-1 WHERE loan_id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: SQL Syntax error , bcs of START TRANSACTION; just because of the Semicolon . can not read next line .

Comment: Are you trying to run the sql in Java..? How are you starting the transaction? Please share the java code

Comment: i have posted the code below , i have failed to run in statement as well preparedstatement .

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off autocommit, then use `Connection.commit()` to end the transaction.

```
connection.setAutocommit(false);
Statement stmt = con2.createStatement();

// this will automatically start a transaction
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT total_installment_remaining  FROM payment_loan WHERE loan_id = 1 FOR UPDATE");

// process the result if needed
...

stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE payment_loan SET total_installment_remaining =total_installment_remaining-1 WHERE loan_id = 1");

// end the transaction and persist then changes
connection.commit();
```

---

If you don't need the result of the SELECT in your code, then you don't really need the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in the first place, because the `UPDATE` will lock the row anyway.

Answer (score -3):

```
String query = "START TRANSACTION;SELECT total_installment_remaining  FROMpayment_loan WHERE loan_id = 1 FOR UPDATE;UPDATE payment_loan SET total_installment_remaining =total_installment_remaining-1 WHERE loan_id = 1;COMMIT;";
    try {
        ps2 = con2.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
        while (rs2.next()) {
            rs2.getInt(1);
        }
        // rs.close();
        // con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("",e);
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: -1, you should use the JDBC API to handle transaction, and not start transactions with statements like this (apart from the fact that almost all drivers only allow you to execute **one** statement per execute, as that is what JDBC defines). Failure to use the JDBC provided methods could lead to invalid states in the driver and weird errors later.